# Need customizable organization chart plugin for my Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, charts

It would be great if anyone could let me know of a simple yet sweet jQuery or any other Javascript plugin for my Rails app, to create customizable (I can add sub-ordinates and superiors) organization charts. I did Google, but didn't find anything appropriate.

I use awesome_nested_set to maintain the tree structure at the back-end.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Ruby library to display and customize an organization chart using [Google's Organization Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/orgchart.html#Overview).

[GoogleVisualR](http://googlevisualr.herokuapp.com/examples/interactive/org_chart)

Answer (score 3):

Lately, I created github repo -- [OrgChart](https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart), it's a jquery plugin used to build any tree-like hierarchy, off course, Organization chart is its classic scenario.The followings are core source code and snapshot of practical results.

```
var datascource = {
  'name': 'Lao Lao',
  'title': 'general manager',
  'children': [
    { 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
    { 'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager',
      'children': [
        { 'name': 'Tie Hua', 'title': 'senior engineer' },
        { 'name': 'Hei Hei', 'title': 'senior engineer',
          'children': [
            { 'name': 'Pang Pang', 'title': 'engineer' },
            { 'name': 'Xiang Xiang', 'title': 'UE engineer' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    { 'name': 'Yu Jie', 'title': 'department manager' }
  ]
};

$('#chart-container').orgchart({
  'data' : datascource,
  'nodeTitle': 'name',
  'nodeContent': 'title'
});
```

[image]

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this library: http://thejit.org/

Specifically this example: http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example2.html

Comment: both links are dead